# SQL Agent and DTSX SSIS package: How to get it to email or ftp the output file? (SQL Server 2016)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a dtsx, and can get SQL Agent to run it as a package on the file system.

So that drops the resulting xlsx to disk.

How can I get that xlsx emailed or sftp'd somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not up to modifying the SSIS package to incorporate email or SFTP, you could add an additional step to the SQL Agent job.

A Transact-SQL script step could be used to call [sp_send_dbmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql) to email the file to the appropriate recipient.

An Operating System step could be used to run an SFTP client (e.g. WinSCP) to transfer the file (though this would probably be better done in another SSIS package--[example](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2015/08/03/accessing-sftp-with-ssis/)).

Comment: I am up to modding a dtsx, but in the import/export tool (that I used to create the dtsx), there is no option (that I see) to send an email. How (or in what tool) do I mod a dtsx to send email?

Comment: SSIS packages are primarily edited using [SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt)

Comment: can I edit the package even if I cannot connect to the production SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the xlsx file path in a user variable instead of hard coding it in the connection.

To do this

- create a package with an excel connection manager
- create a user variable
- In the properties of the excel connection manager set `delayvalidation` to yes and the excelfilepath property to your variable using an expression.

Then in your control flow, after you created the file add a [send mail task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/send-mail-task) and use the same variable to set the attachments property.

If you want to sftp you could use a [script task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/script-task) or a third party component as there is only FTP available in SSIS by default, not sFTP

Comment: Tom, can you call out the tool you use from the start? I don't see options for user variables in the import/export wizard

Comment: @samsmith I don't think it's in the wizard but it's standard in ssis